# React+JavaScript: How to erase data fields after a successful 200 code from sign up page and redirect to login?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Please find my code below for the SignUp react function, once I receive response of 200 after clicking the Sign up button, I want to erase the text in all three fields and redirect the user back to login page. Very new to web development, any help is appreciated!  There are three fields needed to sign up: firstName, email and password.

```
 export default function SignUp() {
      const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState("");
      const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
      const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");

  let sign = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    await ApiService.createUser(
      firstName,
      email,
      password
    )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign up
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="fname"
                name="firstName"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="firstName"
                label="First Name"
                autoFocus
                onChange={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
            onClick={sign}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to be controlling the values on those elements.  I'm going to assume that `TextField` has a property called `value` (otherwise you'll need to find whatever the property should be called).  Something like this:

```
<TextField
    value={firstName}   // <-- here
    autoComplete="fname"
    name="firstName"
    variant="outlined"
    required
    fullWidth
    id="firstName"
    label="First Name"
    autoFocus
    onChange={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
  />
```

Do this with all of your input fields.  That way React will update those fields with the current state any time that changes.  Then you just need to update state after creating the user:

```
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    setFirstName("");
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
})
```

Basically, don't think of it as "updating the fields", but rather separate the management of state from the display of state.  Use the state to drive the display, and update the state as needed.

Comment: Thank you! Can i also link it to login under where I set those fields to ""?

Comment: @new_hello_world: It's not clear what you mean by "link it to login".

Answer (score 1):

For the redirection part, you need to inform us which router you are using.

For instance, if you are using react-router, you can use `useHistory` hook as follow:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

// in your sign function
let history = useHistory()
history.push("/loginPage") // the string '/loginPage' is an example and depend on your routes implementation
```

react-router doc : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Also, you most probably don't need to erase the text-fields since the redirection will unmount your component.

Comment: If I try to do it in the sign function i get this: React Hook "useHistory" is called in function "sign" which is neither a React function component

Comment: got it to work thank you